# Understanding ons.slidingMenu variable in onsen-ui framework

Tags: onsen-ui

please explain me in a words why it works perfect when I call
`ons.slidingMenu.toggleMenu()`
having at the same time `myMenu` as variable of
`<ons-sliding-menu ....var="myMenu">`

I mean I should call `myMenu.toggleMenu()`, not `ons.slidingMenu.toggleMenu()` ....

I think that ons.slidingMenu is defined deep inside onsen. Where I could read about all this hidden vars? (I've found nothing about it in onsen-ui site)

Thanks!

Comment: I use myMenu.toggleMenu() all the time and it worked as expected. It should work both ways. As you can see on their example  'http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/IDvFJ' and look for `ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"`

Comment: Yes it works, but do u know what is ons.slidingMenu ? I have some unpleasant feeling that I did get something in AngularJS ...

Answer (score 3):

It's the same object, but I would advice using the one you get using the `var="..."` attribute.

Actually if you have a navigator you get an `ons.navigator` variable as well. If you have many of the same type of component it will refer to the one that was parsed most recently.